# finding maximum of array for columns starting with spesific letter in sas

Tags: arrays, sas

i have column names starting with same letter but rest of the names are number that dynamically changing. And i have to find maximum of these arrays.

Can i find some solution for this without using number in column names?

for example ,my columns are c5,c7,c9 and their values 12,5,8.

for this array maxofc should be 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no other columns in your dataset begin with 'c'

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  maxofc = max(of c:);
run ;
```

Comment: data want;
set have;

array C:;

Maxi=MAX(of C:);
run; i tried this code before but i guess your code will work. Thank you Chris.

Comment: done! but i couldn't understand why 'array C:' is not necessary in code?

Comment: If you were to use an array, it would be defined as
`array cvars{*} c: ;`. You could then do `maxofc = max(of cvars{*});`